# Framework's strict Content Security Policy header breaks ReCaptcha in production

Tags: ruby, security, http-headers, recaptcha, content-security-policy

I've been experimenting with [Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/guides/) for a little website. It has very strict default security settings in production. Here's the server response headers:

```
cf-ray:2f14dcb05e2307e5-LAX
content-encoding:gzip
content-security-policy:form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'; default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'sha256-IAaN58htbUDxfKhUX+LYHn2kWUEjPKf5lepkdtqd1gU=' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'none'; plugin-types application/pdf; child-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/; media-src 'self'
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Thu, 13 Oct 2016 18:30:19 GMT
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200
via:1.1 vegur
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:DENY
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Something in my content security policy header is not allowing ReCaptcha to work. Keep in mind it **works fine in development on localhost**, with the following response headers:

```
Content-Security-Policy:form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'; default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'sha256-IAaN58htbUDxfKhUX+LYHn2kWUEjPKf5lepkdtqd1gU=' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'none'; plugin-types application/pdf; child-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/; media-src 'self'
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Here's the block which defines CSP for production:

```
# Content Security Policy usage:
      #
      #  * http://content-security-policy.com/
      #  * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy
      #
      # Content Security Policy references:
      #
      #  * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives
      #
      security.content_security_policy %{
        form-action 'self';
        frame-ancestors 'self';
        base-uri 'self';
        default-src 'none';
        script-src 'self' 'sha256-IAaN58htbUDxfKhUX+LYHn2kWUEjPKf5lepkdtqd1gU=' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;
        connect-src 'self';
        img-src 'self' https: data:;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:;
        font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com;
        object-src 'none';
        plugin-types application/pdf;
        child-src 'self';
        frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/;
        media-src 'self'
      }
```

Looks like I need to add a permission to load the scripts. [I'm following Google's own CSP rules](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-using-content-security-policy-csp-on-my-website-how-can-i-configure-it-to-work-with-recaptcha).

What's the issue here?

Edit: Looks like the security policy is disallowing me to load the `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'` script as the `grecaptcha` object is missing from the page.

Comment: google uses `,` as delimiter for `script-src`. You use `space`

Comment: @slowjack2k It just appears to be how the framework is consuming the security policy hash. [Take a look here](https://github.com/hanami/hanami/blob/113eeb41df8e9c5b8d763b2a6e40d68e9ff61885/test/fixtures/security_headers/apps/web/application.rb#L36).

Answer (score -1):

Well as usual, assumption was the mother of all problems.

Hanami's `javascript()` helper actually adds TWO attrs in production - `integrity` and `crossorigin`. The first is used to ascertain that the script hasn't been tampered with - for example if it's from some CDN.

The second, is a bit more vague and when set to "anonymous" by default prevented captcha from working.

Comment: I ended up also using `nonce-` prefix in the CSP array but I don't think it did anything because I've tried that before.